# Is Pyautogui detectable by web scripts?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Is Pyautogui detectable by websites? (I know Selenium can be detectable) I'm going to use it to click and move the mouse. I would like to know if some kind of script can detect clicks and movements made by Pyautogui, I don't know much about web programming and I'm learning to do automations.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/41220267) is many answers how to do selenium undetectable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as far as I know, there is no way for a website to detect the device or software (such as PyAutoGUI) which is making inputs, however, a site *could* detect robotic mouse movement etc., and you will not be able to pass CAPTCHAs.